# показ данных php

Tags: php, html, mysql

У меня такой вопрос. У меня есть 1 база данных usersreg называется там есть 2 таблицы users и sifarisqebulu(заказы на азербайджанском) так вот в сайте можно делать заказы и я хочу что бы после того как я сделал заказ в профиле показалось все заказы.Проблема такая,я использую этот код для отображание данных:

```
`include("dbcon.php");
$sql = 'select * from sifarisqebulu where email="'.$_SESSION['email'].'"';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);`
```

И для отображении:

```
<!-- Default panel contents -->
  <div class="panel-heading"><center>Sifarisler</center></div>


  <!-- Table -->
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
    <th> Link </th>
    <th> IdSifaris </th>
    <th> Qeydler </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> <?php echo $user['link']?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $user['idsifaris']?></td>
    <td> <?php echo $user['sms']?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> <?php echo $user['link']?> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

</div>                              
</div>                              
</div>
```

Такая проблема я вижу тут только один заказ сделанный мною как сделать так чтобы другие заказы показались. Например сделал example@mail.ru заказ один там отабражался да потом второй заказ и второй и так далее помогите?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это потому что [mysqli_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) вытаскивает 1 строку. Нужно обернуть в цикл чтобы вытащить все.

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th> Link </th>
    <th> IdSifaris </th>
    <th> Qeydler </th>
  </tr>
  <?php while ($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
    <tr>
      <td> <?php echo $user['link']?></td>
      <td> <?php echo $user['idsifaris']?></td>
      <td> <?php echo $user['sms']?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Теперь знаете что слуичилось у меня тут в таблице для отображения раньше отображалась первый заказ только первый щас 2 раза второй заказ отображается я хочу первый потом второй потом т.д

Comment: убрал, как мне кажется лишнюю строку из таблицы. Этот цикл отобразит информацию взавизимости от выборки, если что-то повторяется, это значит, что в базе дубликаты

Comment: я конечно блогадарю за вашу помощь но в базе другие ссылки и данные 2 разных заказов я написал ваш код и 2 раза отображается второй заказ

Comment: сделайте выборку из базы и посмотрите данные. Цикл выводит ровно то, что дал запрос. Или же магия еще кокого-то кода, который вы не указали

Comment: а как сделать выборку первого второго третого т.д заказов?

Comment: select * from sifarisqebulu where email="example@mail.ru" - этот запрос запустит в вашем СУБД (PhpMyAdmin или что вы там используете)

Comment: $sql = 'select * from sifarisqebulu where email="'.$_SESSION['email'].'"';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); я вот сделал так почта из сессии хочу чтоб по очереди отображалась по очереди первый заказ потом второй

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59222/discussion-between-sportstubers-and-jurij-jazdanov).